# Idiom for taking absolutely everything from someone

Tags: idiom-requests, translation

In Finnish, there is an idiom for taking everything from someone which translates roughly to "taking even the ashes from the stove". Is there an equivalent saying in English?

Comment: “Take everything from someone”  in what sense?

Answer (score 3):

They'd ***take the shirt of your back***.

From the free dictionary

> the shirt off (one's) back Anything or everything one owns or has to
>   offer. 
> *Those contractors will take the shirt off your back if
>   you hire them. I mean, I paid them an exorbitant amount of money, and
>   look at the shoddy work they did!* 
> *I'm not surprised that Tammy
>   loaned you money—she would give you the shirt off her back if you
>   needed it.*

Answer (score 2):

That phrase reminds me of this one ...

> **bleed (someone or something) dry**.
>   To take all of the resources that another person or thing has available. This phrase is often applied to money.
>   *Paying for my kids' education is just bleeding me dry. I hope I'll still be able to retire one day!
>
>   Overhead costs are bleeding our business dry. We need to come up with a different way of doing things.*
>   https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bleed+him+dry

Answer (score 1):

**Cleaned to the bone** is one option.

> Pacific hurricanes usually breakup over the southern Baja California peninsula and then head north up to Phoenix where they have their annual 'monsoon season.' But that year, the hurricane remnants were following the coast of Baja California and ending up in San Diego. The portable AC shelves in both Costco and Home Depot were cleaned to the bone.

Read more: http://www.city-data.com/forum/san-diego/2921804-may-gray-june-gloom.html#ixzz61hmSAcOi

Answer (score 1):

There are many. Not yet mentioned:

**Wiped him out**

**Cleaned him out**

Him can be replaced by any object pronoun (her, them, us, you).

Answer (score 0):

there's also a nice phrase which is not about stealing money or property but about stealing ideas, praise etc

**steal sb's thunder**

Comment: I'm not sure anyone would take _steal someone's thunder_ as meaning taking everything from them, even if limited to an intellectual level.

Comment: Sure it doesn't have the connotation of 'everything' but it has a similar meaning to stealing the spotlight and to someone that spotlight might be everything